# Lightning Datatable - setActiveCell to openInlineEdit

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

LWC Lightning datatable offers a method to open an inline editor

```
openInlineEdit()
```

which opens `the inline edit panel for the datatable's currently active cell`.
(See here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification)

Unfortunately, if user has previously clicked another row or there are multiple editable cells in a row and user clicked a different one, I can't find a way to specify which cell should be opened for inline edit.

Further, I found `setActiveCell` method inside `datatable.js` but it isn't exposed (because the datatable doesn't expose the column names) so I can't use it due to LWS/Locker.

Is there any way to specify which cell should be opened without cloning the whole datatable from open source repo?